# How do I use bloc and listen for bloc.state manually in dart and NOT through Flutter OR AngularDart's bloc pipe?

Tags: dart, bloc

I am following the pattern suggested in bloc for having my bloc's call my repositories that wrap my api client classes that make RESTful calls to my API. I am putting all of this in a common library that is shared between Flutter and Angular dart as per the pattern shown in the bloc tutorials. I'd like to learn how to dispatch the same events to my blocs that Flutter and Angular dart use from a dart CLI program that I am also writing and listen for the changes in state and get the data returned from the API. (I could have the dart CLI program all the repositories directly, but I wanted to do everything through dispatching events to the blocs.)

Almost of the coding examples and usages for Bloc where the blocs are consumed by applications that I can find are based on Flutter. There are a few here and there for AngularDart (and those use the bloc pipe, predominately). I see very few examples of using Bloc manually in other Dart code such as a CLI/console program **or** in unit testing.

I would like to write a simple CLI to make my API calls through dispatching Bloc events and responding to the changes in state from the Bloc. (I am very accustomed to using ngRx and Angular to manage state, and I am trying to find a good pattern to follow here for straight dart code and for dart unit testing to call my blocs. I am quite used to the ngRx pattern of Effects that make API calls and writing selectors and listening to them for changes in state (RxJs code). I have had difficulty translating this to dart/bloc.

I could use some code examples or suggestions for calling my blocs and listening for state changes and getting the state from the API calls that are made. I would like to do this from OUTSIDE the bloc (such as with the .state property) and not be overriding the methods within Bloc such as the transforms. (Perhaps a delegate is a good way to go, I don't know.. it seems like using the .state property would be ideal.)

A scenario I am looking at is dispatching an event (ItemQuery) to a bloc. This event tells the bloc to make an api call which returns a list of items from the server. The bloc returns state (ItemsLoading) immediately in mapeventtostate when the call starts. When the api call completes, the bloc returns state (ItemsLoaded) and that state contains the List returned from the API call. (Failure would return (ItemsErrorState).

I'd need a head start how to setup dart code to have a listener to watch for the state changes from my bloc. Once the listener is setup, then the code dispatches the LoadItems event, and the listener waits for the state changes of (ItemsLoading) and (ItemsLoaded) then gets the List from the ItemsLoaded state - not using Flutter or Angular Dart - all in straight dart code. Suitable examples on the web or in stackoverlow elsewhere would be great.

I have tried calling my bloc through using dart unit tests successfully.

I was able to get this code to work in test to test the order of events received (in this case filtering the list to 1 item). This, however, doesn't really help me on getting the data from the ItemStateLoaded event during a test or help me in dispatching the ItemQuery event from a Dart CLI program I am writing and getting the Item(s) returned in the ItemStateLoaded.

This test works:

```
test('ItemBloc - Query filter for id == 1', () {
      ItemBloc ib = ItemBloc();

      expectLater(
          ib.state,
          emitsInOrder([
            new TypeMatcher<InitialItemState>(),
            new TypeMatcher<ItemStateLoading>(),
            new TypeMatcher<ItemStateLoaded>()
          ]));
      ApiDataConfig c = new ApiDataConfig()
        ..filter = 'id eq 1';
      ib.dispatch(ItemQuery());
    });
```

I am quite a bit stuck and would like to see how to consume my API results in the bloc from straight dart code and not through Flutter or Angular Dart's bloc pipe. I'd like to get the list of items that is returned in the ItemStateLoaded event from straight dart code.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question (which was a long one). The answer was quite simple, as I am just learning Dart and Bloc.

My project setup for this "Item application" has a folder structure like:

- item_angular - folder for the angular dart "item web app"
- item_flutter - folder for the flutter "item mobile app"
- item_common - Blocs and common code shared between the two

That folder structure above is per the examples in the bloc tutorial. I added another folder:

- item_cli - cli application that utilizes the same Blocs in
  item_common that the angluar and flutter applications use.

The example code of calling the bloc in item_common that works is:

```
_handleItemEvent(ItemState state) {
  if (state is InitialItemState) {
    print('Initial Item State');
  }
  if (state is ItemStateLoading) {
    print('Loading...');
  }
  if (state is ItemStateLoaded) {
    print('Loaded... ' + jsonEncode(state.items[0]));
  }
  if (state is ItemStateError) {
    print('Error ' + state.error);
  }
}

main() async {
  ItemBloc ib = ItemBloc();
  ib.state.listen(_handleItemEvent, onDone: ib.dispose);
  print('Listening');
  ib.dispatch(ItemQuery());
}
```

This code creates the ItemBloc, subscribes to the stream of events through ib.listen, dispatches the Query event to tell the Bloc to make the web api call to get the items. The Bloc yields the Loading state then it calls the repository layer to make the API call to get the items and yields the Loaded state which contains the received items once it successfully receives them.

The output looks like:

```
Listening..
Initial Item State
Loading...
Loaded... [{the json objects returned}]
```

This pattern answers the question of directly using the Bloc in a CLI application using straight dart code (no dependencies on Flutter or AngularDart). The Bloc in the common library is shared between AngularDart and Flutter and also with the dart CLI maintenance application.